# $trigger - error with <x-dropdown> in Laravel Breeze

Tags: laravel

```
     <x-dropdown class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <xd-item>1</xd-item>
        <xd-item>2</xd-item>
     </x-dropdown>
```

When using this code in Laravel breeze, I get the error "Undefined variable $trigger". What is causing the error and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error of trigger comes because you need specify inside x-dropdown the tag x-slot with name property trigger

```
<x-slot name="trigger"><label>Drop Example</label></x-slot>
```

Remember define the property align and width for x-dropdown and for the options you need specify inside the dropdown tag another x-slot with the name content

```
<x-slot name="content"><x-dropdown-link>Option1</x-dropdown-link></x-slot>
```

You can read in this link, i used into my project too https://webmobtuts.com/backend-development/building-a-simple-cms-with-laravel-breeze/